# POST json array and get response as json array

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

my client is sending me a POST with a json-array and is awaiting a response with the complete details of the requested data. I have no problems with single requests and single responses, but to minimize the overhead, I'd like to process an array.

my models.py

```
class RoFile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=True)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
    md5check = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
```

one try of my serializer:

```
class RoFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    deleted = serializers.ReadOnlyField(required=False)
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(required=False)
    info = serializers.ReadOnlyField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = RoFile
        fields = (
            'filename', 'md5check', 'deleted', 'user', 'info',
        )

   def create(self, validated_data):
        return RoFile(**validated_data)
```

on try of my views:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def rofile_detaillist(request, format=None):
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    serializer = RoFileSerializer(data=data, many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        json_add = []
        for x in serializer.validated_data:
            try:
                rofile = RoFile.objects.filter(md5check=x['md5check'])
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                continue

            *invalid code here*

        return Response(jsonarraywithallinfos)
    else:
        return Resonse(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

another view try:

```
class RoFileDetailList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = RoFile
    serializer_class = RoFileSerializer(many=True)

    def get_queryset(self):
         return Rofile.objects.filter(md5check=self.request.data['md5check'])
```

a POST example:

```
{"filename": "filename1.exe", "md5check": "f8541061779b1efc5c30c4783edfb8f8"},
{"filename": "filename2.exe", "md5check": "16cdac5eb0ec829c2e2c199488681f6e"}
```

what I need as a response back:

```
{"filename": "filename1.exe", "md5check": "f8541061779b1efc5c30c4783edfb8f8", user: "testuser1", deleted: "True", info: ""},
{"filename": "filename2.exe", "md5check": "16cdac5eb0ec829c2e2c199488681f6e", user: "testuser1", deleted: "False", info: ""}
```

Sorry for the invalid code part, but I have already tried so much, so I deleted that part (by accident).
Thank you!

**EDIT:**

I don't need to create with POST, I only need to retrieve additional data (the rest of the model). I had to change the create function in the serializer, because I don't want to create the entries, I only want to retrieve the data associated with the md5check from the db.

thanks to @zaphod100.10
my actual serializer:

```
class RoFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RoFile
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('deleted',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return RoFile(**validated_data)
```

my view:

```
class RoFileListDetailApi(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RoFileSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return RoFile.objects.filter(md5check=self.request.data['md5check'])

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, headers=headers)
```

my post:

```
{"filename": "filename1.exe", "md5check": "f8541061779b1efc5c30c4783edfb8f8"},
{"filename": "filename2.exe", "md5check": "16cdac5eb0ec829c2e2c199488681f6e"}
```

my actual response is now a list but only with my POST-data and not the real data from the db:

```
{"filename": "filename1.exe", "md5check": "f8541061779b1efc5c30c4783edfb8f8", deleted: false, info: null, user: null},
{"filename": "filename2.exe", "md5check": "16cdac5eb0ec829c2e2c199488681f6e", deleted: false, info: null, user: null}
```

should be:

```
{"filename": "filename1.exe", "md5check": "f8541061779b1efc5c30c4783edfb8f8", deleted: true, info: "some info", user: "usertest1"},
{"filename": "filename2.exe", "md5check": "16cdac5eb0ec829c2e2c199488681f6e", deleted: false, info: "some info2", user: "usertest2"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
class RoFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = RoFile
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('deleted', 'user', 'info')

class RoFileListCreateApi(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RoFileSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
         return Rofile.objects.filter(md5check=self.request.data['md5check'])

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        # override perform_create or the serializers create method for custom create logic
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        # assign other fields to the objs and save again
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

You just have to pass many=True to the serializer for handling lists.

Override perform_create method in the generic view or the serializers create method for applying custom creation logic.

**EDIT:**

based on new info provided I have changed the create method.

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    # don't create anything just insert required data
    for rof_data in serializer.data:
        md5check = rof_data['md5check']
        # code to retrieve data from db based on md5check
        ....
        # code to insert values in rof_data
        rof_data['user'] = user.username
        rof_data['deleted'] = deleted
        rof_data['info'] = info
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: thank you, I don't want to create them, because they are already in the db. I only need to make the query to get the additional data. Please see my edit.

Comment: @bingobear I updated the answer yesterday. Did it work out?